# Laravel Telescope won't remove

Tags: laravel

After running `composer remove laravel/telescope` It still won't remove telescope completely. I've followed the answer here https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/361 but to no avail it still doesn't work. Here's the error message

[image]

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: Can you check in your `config/app.php`, in the `providers` array if you included the laravel telescope there.

Comment: @aceraven777 I'm currently using the latest version which is 6.1.0. 
and yes I included `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class` in the `config/app.php`
I tried commenting it but nothing happened, no errors, telescope still there, nothing. I also tried following this [link](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/639)

Comment: You will have to remove that in the `app.php`

Comment: remove it after `composer remove` OR remove it before `composer remove`?

Comment: Remove it before `composer remove`

Comment: Still produces the same error.

Comment: can you run `composer dumpautoload`. Then `composer remove`

Comment: Still the same error, what I did was after the first fail I reverted back by using **git**, so telescope is still there. Then I tried your suggestion to remove the `telescope provider` then ran `composer dumpautoload`, then ran `composer remove laravel/telescope` but still produces the same error as my problem.

Comment: In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` is there a `TelescopeServiceProvider` there? Remove that also.

Comment: Oh ma Goodness that was all that was needed to do, Thank you so much man really appreciate you helping out.

Comment: I will post this as an answer. Please mark my answer as best answer. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must first remove all the `telescope` reference in your code before running `composer remove laravel/telescope`.

1. Kindly check `config/app.php`, under `providers` array, remove the Telescope there
2. In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` is there a `TelescopeServiceProvider` there? Remove that also.
3. Remove `telescope.php` in `config` folder

Then finally you can run `composer remove laravel/telescope`.

Comment: also remove public/vendor/telescope

Comment: i also had to remove `bootstrap/cache/config.php` to get rid of link to `TelescopeServiceProvider`

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

Inside:

```
 root->config->telescope.php
```

in the `telescope.php` config file:

```
'enabled' => env('TELESCOPE_ENABLED', 'true'),
```

I changed the `true` to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just disable `Telescope` temporarily, in your `composer.json` file add `laravel/telescope` to the `dont-discover` index:

```
"laravel": {
        "dont-discover": ["laravel/telescope"]
}
```

then run the `composer dump` command.

To permanently remove the telescope, run the `composer remove laravel/telescope` command, then remove `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class,` from `config/app.php` file and delete `TelescopeServiceProvider` file from `app/providers/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove it before the composer remove `laravel/telescope`

- Remove the file `config/telescope.php`
- Go on `config/app.php` find "App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class" this line remove
- Go to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` on the register function and remove this line thing

```
if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
  $this->app->register(\Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
  $this->app->register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
}
```

- Remove one line on the `composer.json`

```json
"laravel": {
  "dont-discover": [
    "laravel/telescope"
  ]
}
```

TO

```
"dont-discover": []
```

Then run a command on terminal

```
composer remove laravel/telescope
```